# How do I get the correct Context for an OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to open a custom dialog when a user clicks on a `LinearLayout` using the following code:

```
    each_pays = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.each_pays);

    each_pays_vert.setOnClickListener(new LinearLayout.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View _v) {
            // custom dialog
            final Dialog multiples_dialog = new Dialog(this);
            multiples_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            multiples_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.multiples_dialog);

            Button closeMultiplesDialogButton = (Button) multiples_dialog.findViewById(R.id.close_multiples_button);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            closeMultiplesDialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    multiples_dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            multiples_dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

The custom dialog code etc works elsewhere (when run from an option menu item click, for example), but when I try it here I get a compile time error `Error:(303, 71) error: incompatible types: Intent cannot be converted to Context`.

The error is in the line:

```
final Dialog multiples_dialog = new Dialog(this);
```

If I replace `this` with `getApplicationContext()` I get a run time crash.

I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration is inside of a Object-Declaration (OnClickListener). So `this` is not your Activity in this case, but the OnClickListener.

Three options to work around:

- reference the activity for example with `final Dialog multiples_dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this)`
- put the code to show the dialog in a separate function in your Activity and call that function in your OnClickListener.
- save a reference to the Context to be used within the OnClickListener, (mark it as final). This option would look something like this:

'

```
each_pays = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.each_pays);
final Context ctx = this;
each_pays_vert.setOnClickListener(new LinearLayout.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View _v) {
        // custom dialog
        final Dialog multiples_dialog = new Dialog(ctx);
        ...
```

Note: the Application Context can not be used for any UI-actions. This is the reason of the crash when using getApplicationContext().

Comment: I used the first option (`MainActivity.this`) as a quick fix, but will probably implement via your second suggestion as soon as I get a chance to rework a few bits of code as that seems more 'correct' and less of a quick-fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a `Context` from a `View` by using [`getContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()):

```
final Dialog multiples_dialog = new Dialog(_v.getContext());
```